# Wrote a program to get reverse of a string in python doesn't work fine

Tags: python, string

First I wrote a statment to reverse a string

```
name="geoffrey"
reversename=name[len(name)-1:-1:-1]
print("Ther reverse of the name is ",reversename)
```

which doesn't return the reverse of the name ,then changes the value

```
name="geoffrey"
reversename=name[len(name)-1:0:-1]
print("Ther reverse of the name is ",reversename)
```

works but returns only yerffoe

Comment: Hope this will help **reversename=name[len(name)-1::-1]**

Comment: Thank you it worked finally  .